# What considerations must you take into account before you can attempt to configure clustering on your network?

Tags: cluster

I work as a computer network manager for a large software company. My company sells its software through a web site that is hosted on the company's network. As the company grows, we find that the web server cannot handle the load generated by the traffic on the site. I need to come up with a solution for managing the load on the server, and clustering came to mind. What considerations must I take into account before I can attempt to configure clustering on my network? What must I do in order to analyze business and application requirements? How can I plan storage methods? How can I plan server capacity? How can I plan failover policies?

Comment: "I work as a computer network manager for a large software company" - erk!

Answer (score 4):

"Formal" clustering is complex and not something I'd look at for a web server due to the complexity probably not being needed.

Have you looked at simple load balancing? Have you considered looking at the website to see if its been coded efficiently to scale, e.g. separate servers for static content such as images, etc? If you use a lot of SSL then have you considered SSL accelerators to move that workload off the web server?

Answer (score 0):

I see many questions here, and I believe, these can be best answered with more information.
I suggest you start with a good resource to understand the concepts.
If you are looking for Microsoft Cluster, http://technet.microsoft.com
Clusters are basically two types: 1) Failover  2) N/w load balancing.

First, decide which way you want to go and then take it from there.
If you are looking for clustered web server, I suggest you start here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778748(WS.10).aspx

Checklist: Planning and creating a server cluster: is also a good start
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757338%28WS.10%29.aspx

You will find lots of information about Microsoft Clustering here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/